SQL Index Scan not finding value that sequential scan finds
I've got a query:
select * from table where table.entity = '->...'

And when this query is run it returns no results. select * from table where table.entity like '->...' does return a result.
At first I thought it was due to some non ascii character (entity is a varchar(40)) so I made a select ascii(substring(#,1)) query and ran through all 40 characters but they worked as expected, no special hidden characters.
The only difference between the = and like cases I can find is that the like case uses a Seq Scan and not an Index Scan when I run explain analyze.
The index is CREATE INDEX table_entity ON public.table USING btree (entity NULLS FIRST, primary_key NULLS FIRST)
The string '->...' has a fairly common to the database prefix, 315 of the 1043 records share the prefix. I've notice that this is an issue for all strings that start with ->, and when running this query select * from table ORDER BY entity NULLS FIRST, primary_key NULLS FIRST It seems to ignore the -> and just focus on the values, so it would look like "->","Aaron","->Abagail",... where it's ordered but just ignoring the ->
EDIT:
Reindexing solved the original issue. But the ORDER BY still is ordered weird. Is there an explanation for that?

Check the collation settings of the database and the specific column using SELECT collation_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'table' AND column_name = 'entity';
If you need a specific sorting behavior, you might consider changing the collation of the column to a more suitable one, or use the COLLATE keyword in your queries to specify how to sort the data.

You are experiencing data corruption.
From the string you are searching for, I would guess that the cause is that you upgraded the operating system. An upgrade of the C library (or the ICU library, if you are using ICU collations) can lead to changes in the collations provided by the library, and since PostgreSQL uses these collations, it can corrupt indexes on string expressions.
Rebuild all indexes on strings.
See this article for more.
